# Orden de parametros. PHP

Tags: php, ordenamiento

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Estoy leyendo el libro PANDA PHP para principiantes, y en una sección aparece
**Orden de los parámetros, que tengo que pasar**

Donde obtengo dicho orden?
Cual es el orden idóneo?

Comment: ¿Podrás agregar un poco más de texto del libro para dar contexto a la pregunta?

Comment: Las funciones en PHP con cadena de texto, u otro condiciones que conlleva parámetros debe respetar un orden lógico para obtener mi petición. Estos llevan un orden?

Comment: Que funcion usas, o que ejercicio estas desarrollando??, así como esta tu pregunta es dificil de entender que es lo que quieres hacer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pues tu pregunta es muy genérica, pero si te refieres a que parámetros y en que orden se deben pasar a una función, esto depende directamente de la función que vayas a usar (ya sea una función propia de PHP o una que tu mismo desarrolles), cada función define el número de parámetros que necesita, su orden y si por ejemplo es obligatorio o no.

A modo de ejemplo puedes ver la función [split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php), la cuál sirve para separar una cadena en un array por un carácter en específico; si te fijas en la documentación se define cada parametro, su descripción y su orden. En el caso específico de la función split, tiene 3 parámetros en este orden:

- pattern: Carácter por el cual separar la cadena
- string: Cadena que se va separar por el carácter del parámetro (1)
- limit: Número máximo de elementos del array (este es opcional, se puede pasar o no a la función cuando la vas a usar)

Teniendo en cuenta esta documentación, de esta función, la forma de usarla sería

```
$partes = split("-", "frase-de-prueba");
// Esto retorna un array de 3 elementos array("frase", "de", "prueba"), ya que se está separando la cadena por el carácter guion (-)
```

Se debe usar así y solo así, pues en ese orden la función split espera los parametros. Así mismo cuando desarrolles una función propia, tu defines el orden y la cantidad de parámetros que vayas a usar.